# Value returned from function

Tags: java, methods

Suppose I've the following class:

```
class A{
    private Map<String, String> map;

    private Map<String, String> getMap(){
        return map;
    }

    private doActionOnMap(){
        Map<String, String> map = getMap(); //Is the map returned by getMap() 
                                            //refers to the private field map?
    }
}
```

That is, when some value returns by method it will be another (copy of the original) object or it will refer to the object located inside method?

Comment: Obviously the same, but since you never assigned it, you will just get null.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reference...when you want a clone, you will have to implement it yourself

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference type so all that you will get is a reference to the original object. It is not a copy.

I suggest you look up the difference between reference and value types

[Reference Types](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_10.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<String, String> map;
```

`map` is a class member, it's associated with each instance of the class. If you write:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = a.getMap();
```

You'll get a reference and not a copy of it. If you change it, it'll be changed for all methods using it in this class.